# What's the cause of this link error when I try to link my executable to my library by name?

Tags: c++, cmake, clang++

I'm trying to build and run project that links files based on the picked C++ standard.
The project file structure looks like this:

```
.
├── CMakeLists.txt
├── cpp-version-test
│   ├── CMakeLists.txt
│   ├── test-cpp17.cpp
│   ├── test-cpp17.hpp
│   ├── test-cpp20.cpp
│   └── test-cpp20.hpp
└── main.cpp
```

In the top CMakeLists.txt I set C++ standard like this:

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED True)
```

Inside `cpp-version-test` CMakeLists.txt file I run conditional:

```
if(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD GREATER_EQUAL 20)
    message("C++20 choosen, building test-cpp20")
    add_library(cpp_version_test OBJECT test-cpp20.cpp)
else()
    message("C++20 not choosen, building test-cpp17")
    add_library(cpp_version_test OBJECT test-cpp17.cpp)
endif()

target_include_directories(cpp_version_test INTERFACE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR})
```

And back inside the top CMakeLists.txt I glue it with the following snippet:

```
add_subdirectory(cpp-version-test)
list(APPEND EXTRA_LIBS cpp-version-test)

add_executable(Template main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(Template PUBLIC ${EXTRA_LIBS} compiler_flags)

target_include_directories(Template PUBLIC
    "${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}"
)
```

`cmake --build` runs fine, Clang clogs up on linking:

```
[ 33%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/Template.dir/main.cpp.o
[ 66%] Linking CXX executable Template
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lcpp-version-test: No such file or directory
clang-15: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/Template.dir/build.make:97: Template] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:100: CMakeFiles/Template.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:91: all] Error 2
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. It's my back and forth with learning CMake.

Comment: As an alternative to consider, you could create just one cpp file and use macros to conditionally compile based on the standard version.

Comment: `linker command failed with exit code 1` There must be more useful error messages above that final message.

Comment: @Brian that's definitely more sane solution, but since I'm learning build systems, I stray away from such.

Comment: @273K Yes, you're right. I updated the post.

Comment: You confused hyphens and underscores, `add_library(cpp_version_test ...` and `list(... cpp-version-test)`

Comment: @273K Thank you! That and sleep deprivation were the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do this in your subdirectory:

```
add_library(cpp_version_test OBJECT ...)
```

Then in your top CMakeLists.txt:

```
add_subdirectory(cpp-version-test)
list(APPEND EXTRA_LIBS cpp-version-test)
add_executable(Template main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(Template PUBLIC ${EXTRA_LIBS} compiler_flags)
```

You mixed up the name of your directory and the name of your target. You target is named with underscores and your directory with dashes. `target_link_libraries` works with target names and not directory names. Your "`list(APPEND EXTRA_LIBS cpp-version-test)`" should instead be "`list(APPEND EXTRA_LIBS cpp_version_test)`".

Some additional feedback: Instead of doing things the way you're doing, I would let the user set a cache variable named something like "`CPP_VERSION_TEST_CXX_LANGUAGE_STANDARD`" to choose the number of the C++ language version to use and then `target_compile_features(cpp_version_test <VISIBILITY> "cxx_std_${CPP_VERSION_TEST_CXX_LANGUAGE_STANDARD}")`. See docs:

- https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_compile_features.html
- https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_gbl/CMAKE_CXX_KNOWN_FEATURES.html#high-level-meta-features-indicating-c-standard-support